# Github action doesn't work with GCP. 403: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I am trying to create a GithubAction job, which should authenticate in GCP via Identity federation and upload some files to a bucket.

[Here](https://github.com/vyshkov/gcp-serverless/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy-backend.yaml) is the full source code of GitHub action.

In this job I have such a step which doesn't work:

```
    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/736194043976/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider'
        service_account: 'githubsa@learning-words-trial.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
        token_format: 'access_token'
```

Unfortunately, it fails with 403 error:

```
Error: google-github-actions/auth failed with: retry function failed after 1 attempt: failed to generate Google Cloud access token for githubsa@learning-words-trial.iam.gserviceaccount.com: (403) {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My service account `githubsa@learning-words-trial.iam.gserviceaccount.com` has enough permissions:

[image]

And the principal is set (i added random roles for testing):
[image]

Also, `my-pool` and `my-provider` are configured according to the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions) and connected with the service account.

Here is an audit log from GCP:

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist)."
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "serviceAccountDelegationInfo": [
        {}
      ],
      "principalSubject": "principal://iam.googleapis.com/projects/736194043976/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/subject/repo:vyshkov/gcp-serverless:ref:refs/heads/main"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "172.176.229.16",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "google-github-actions:auth/1.0.0,gzip(gfe)",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2023-02-26T15:54:55.543085043Z",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "iamcredentials.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "GenerateAccessToken",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken",
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/-/serviceAccounts/103065049355271736573",
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.iam.credentials.v1.GenerateAccessTokenRequest",
      "name": "projects/-/serviceAccounts/githubsa@learning-words-trial.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "identityDelegationChain": [
        "projects/-/serviceAccounts/githubsa@learning-words-trial.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "sbbvpke10rst",
  "resource": {
    "type": "service_account",
    "labels": {
      "unique_id": "103065049355271736573",
      "email_id": "githubsa@learning-words-trial.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "project_id": "learning-words-trial"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-02-26T15:54:55.523760524Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/learning-words-trial/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "operation": {
    "id": "14170752551549534963",
    "producer": "iamcredentials.googleapis.com",
    "first": true,
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-02-26T15:54:56.249222142Z"
}
```

Can you please point me to where I could make a mistake?

Answer (score 8):

A 403 Permission denied error such as `Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist)` is due to the principalSet on the service account IAM binding not matching the principalSubject making the call.

It is useful to enable Audit logging for iam.googleapis.com and sts.googleapis.com. Refer to [public docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging/examples-workload-identity) for more details.

The STS token is used to [impersonate a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation#impersonation) that the principalSubject has been granted roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser role. Additional details on granting access [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds#allow_the_external_workload_to_impersonate_the_service_account).

Comment: You are probably right.
I recreated the OIDC provider with these attributes: `--attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.repository=assertion.repository"` instead of `--attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub,attribute.actor=assertion.actor,attribute.aud=assertion.aud"` and now it woks. So the problem is in attribute-mapping. To be honest I am not really confident what exactly is in `attribute.aud` and `assertion.aud`.

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation that explains how a branch or an environment is represented in the  --attribute-mapping VS PrinciplaSet .
which is a shame (AWS and Azure made way simpler to map tokenID with OIDC Identity).
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.workloadIdentityPools.providers#WorkloadIdentityPoolProvider.FIELDS.attribute_mapping



I want to create a mapping for   MY_REPO+ ref:refs/heads/git_actions + Environment: Myenv and I can't find the right mapping for over a week now

Answer (score 5):

you should add the role iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator and if necessary also iam.serviceAccountUser:

```bash
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "$SERVICE_ACCOUNT@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --project="${PROJECT_ID}" --role="roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" --member=serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: That was a missing part for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone facing that problem please also double-check that `repo` is in format: `username/repo_name`or `org/repo_name`.

From docs:

> repository: Contains the owner and repository name–for example "google/guava".

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-deployment-pipelines