# Github Actions: Unable to acquire impersonated credentials

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to create a Github Action that will replicate my Firestore database to a specific bucket using [this](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-automated-backups/) tutorial but I've decided to use keyless authentication from Github actions as opposed to a downloadable service account.

In my .yaml file is the following code:

```
name: Backup Firestore

on: workflow_dispatch

env:
  PROJECT_ID: my_project
  BUCKET: gs://my_bucket

jobs:
  backup:
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - id: auth
        name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: wipinformation
          service_account: myserviceaccount@myproject.gserviceaccount.com
      - run: gcloud info
      - run: gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
      - run: gcloud firestore export $BUCKET
```

I face the following error when i try to log in:

> ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.export) There was a problem refreshing your
> current auth tokens: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials',
> '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission
> 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may
> not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n
> {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n
> "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        "domain":
> "iam.googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "permission":
> "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n
> }\n}\n')

Based on the research that I've done on this issue, other users with the same issue either have typos in their code or its service account permissions. I've done this from scratch twice so I doubt its typos. The two permissions I started with are for "Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin" and "Storage Admin", I have added "Service Account Token Creator", "Service Account User" and "Workload Identity User" to an existing service account but I'm facing the same issue.

Is there a permission missing? It could be the code as well. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know that its not your first intention but have you tried to use the SA key to at least test that the project, sa name, variables and related configuration are alright?

Does it fail only on the gcloud firestore export $BUCKET step? What if you hardcode the bucket name or try to execute another dummy gcloud command?

Comment: The SA key version works. Yes, it fails on the last step only, its able to authenticate etc. The bucket is hardcoded at the top in the environment variables.

Comment: Had you check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573270/github-action-doesnt-work-with-gcp-403-permission-iam-serviceaccounts-getacc

and this?
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions

Comment: Not sure how i missed these 2 but they really helped, thanks.

Comment: Great! if you can please share what was the issue so everyone else can see it!

Comment: I don't mind sharing a solution but just to be clear, i actually didn't find a solution per se, i just used service account version instead of WIP. I thought service account key version couldn't be used anymore but your answer prompted me to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the SA Key version instead of WIP.

```
name: Backup Firestore with SA Key

# on: workflow_dispatch
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 02 * * *"

env:
  PROJECT_ID: project_name
  BUCKET: gs://bucket_name

jobs:
  backup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - id: auth
        name: Authenticate with Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true
      - run: gcloud info
      # - run: gcloud auth login
      - run: gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
      - run: gcloud firestore export $BUCKET
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody else comes along with the same problem. This error seems to originate from a failure to validate attributes due to missing mapping (as apposed to a mapped assertion mismatch).

I had the same issue when using OIDC with Github Actions. I had a service account with a custom role and the relevant permissions for (in my case) Artifact Repo and `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`.

Everything else was set up ok, I had the service account, identity pool and and provider set up with the mapped service account. I was getting the same error as the OP.

In my case the issue was with my OIDC provider attribute mapping. I was trying to allow-list a specific repo, similarly to the below:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gh-actions-pre-prod@foo-bar-1337.iam.gserviceaccount.com \  
    --role=roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/12345678/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-actions-ci-pre-prod/subject/repo:myorg/myrepo"
```

What I seemed to be missing was [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-deployment-pipelines):

> Note: You can only check attributes that you've configured in the
> attribute mapping in the configuration for your workload identity pool
> provider.

I added the `repository_id` attribute to the mappings and updated my command.

[image]

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding gh-actions-pre-prod@foo-bar-1337.iam.gserviceaccount.com \  
        --role=roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
        --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/12345678/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/gh-actions-ci-pre-prod/attribute.repository_id/31337"
```

Hopefully this is of some use to anybody else having similar problems.